# Setting up Codecov for private GitHub repository

Tags: code-coverage, codecov

Really liked this post https://agostini.tech/2017/07/16/code-coverage-with-codecov and it helped me to setup codecov for my repositories, but the feature “codecov will generate a mini code coverage report and post it as a comment to the pull request”, I am getting it for a public repository of mine easily, but, not for a private one. Is there any specific procedure for private repositories?

Comment: It's also possible to get that for private repositories. Did you add token in your Continuous Integration file ? I am using jacoco and it works pretty well. I started using cobertura but unfortunately it didn't work. To help you, please can I know more about your problem ? My project used java & maven. Hope you already solved your problem.

Comment: Yes, the problem was solved, it was actually a build script issue. But anyway thanks.